# find and replace string in xml but replace string is already present in same xml

Tags: xml, shell

I have a multiple entry in xml file like below

```
   <Suggestion keyword="R. 233-32-2" label="R. 233-32-2"/>
   <Suggestion keyword="R. 832-2" label="R.832-2"/>
   .
   . 
   <Suggestion keyword="A. 432-2" label="A.432-2"/>
```

I would like to replace the label value with the keyword value. can someone tell me how can i do it ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<AFS>
    <Suggestions> 
        <Suggestion keyword="D. 1143-8" label="D.1143-8"/> <Suggestion keyword="R. 242-71" label="R.242-71"/> <Suggestion keyword="222-26" label="222-26"/>
        <Suggestion keyword="L. 250-7" label="L.250-7"/> <Suggestion keyword="281 M" label="281 M"/> 
    </Suggestions> 
</AFS>
```

Comment: please provide the xml and language you are familiar with and what you tried.

Comment: i know the shell scripting. i tried to write a shell script but it is not working as expected

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AFS>
  <Suggestions>
    <Suggestion keyword="D. 1143-8" label="D.1143-8"/>
    <Suggestion keyword="R. 242-71" label="R.242-71"/>
    <Suggestion keyword="222-26" label="222-26"/>
    .......

Comment: <Suggestion keyword="L. 250-7" label="L.250-7"/>
    <Suggestion keyword="281 M" label="281 M"/>
  </Suggestions>
</AFS>